# Calls to next() on abstract class that implements Iterator<E> returns Object instead of E

Tags: java, generics

I have a class with the following definition:

```
public abstract class A<T> implements Iterator<B> {}
```

The following call to next() will return an Object rather than a B:

```
A a = new SomethingThatExtendsA();
B b = a.next();
```

I've searched for quite awhile and haven't been able to figure out why this next() call fails to compile. Is anyone able to describe this behavior for me?

Edited original to be templated, as this seems to matter.

Edit for additional clarification: This is a compile-time issue, not a runtime issue. The implementation of SomethingThatExtendsA(); should be irrelevant in this case at compile-time.

Comment: Can you please post the code of the `SomethingThatExtendsA` class?

Comment: I'm sorry h3nr1x, I cannot post the exact code. Are you able to describe a situation to me where its implementation could/would possibly matter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So we have this code:

```
public abstract class A<T> implements Iterator<B> {}
[...]
A a = new SomethingThatExtendsA();
a.next();
```

`A` is a generic type, but you have defined `a` with a raw type. Ignore the right hand side of the `=`, we are only interested in the static type:

```
A/*<Something>*/ a = ...;
```

The compiler should give you warnings here. (At least relatively recent versions of javac will do - `rawtypes` warning in Oracle javac.) Take notice of your compiler's warnings. (Wasn't it nice when javac didn't give warnings?)

So now we are in a situation that `a` has a type that is both raw and is a `Iterator<B>`. This is a really confusing situation with just mind-blowingly difficult implications. We shouldn't even be doing this - we should be avoiding mixing generic and raw types. So the Java Language Specification takes the simple way out and discards the partial generic type information.

So, don't mix raw and generic types. Just use all generics and you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm fairly new to serious Java, and your answer mostly makes sense to me. From what I understand, no implementation of `SomethingThatExtendsA` could affect the compilation of `B b = a.next();`. If this is not true, could you provide an example?

Comment: Oops, that parenthetical comment I put in is silly. No it's the fact that you have declared the static type of `a` using `A a` instead of `A<Something> a`. It doesn't matter what value you've assigned to it. (I'll edit.)

Answer (score 0):

```
public abstract class A implements Iterator<B> {}
class B {}
class SomethingThatExtendsA extends A {
// implement A methods
}
A a = new SomethingThatExtendsA();
a.next();
```

This code is pretty correct and returns B object. Probably you missed something in `SomethingThatExtendsA` class.

Test it by calling:

```
B b1 = new Object();  // compilation error
B b2 = a.next(); // all is OK
```

**UPDATE:**
Change signature in SomethingThatExtendsA from
`public Object next() { }` to `public B next() {}`

Comment: Sorry mishadoff, I missed a key part of the class definition during my simplification and edited the question. Can you please re-examine?

Comment: If you have typed class `A` use the same type in extension `SomethingThatExtendsA extends A<T>` but provide actual value of type `T` by the way you should define next method in `A` class OR use following assignment `SomethingThatExtendsA sa = new SomethingThatExtendsA();`

Comment: I cannot do `SomethingThatExtendsA sa = new SomethingThatExtendsA();` I have over-simplified the code here - how my instance of A comes into existence should not matter to the compiler. If you can explain a situation where the implementation of SomethingThatExtendsA affects the compile-time behavior of a.next(),  I will reexamine my oversimplification.

Comment: This is hack. Just define `B next()` in `A` and then override it in `SA` or change return type direct in SA

Comment: Yeah, I've noticed that fixes the issue, but it sucks that I have to do something so hacky :(. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @mishadoff: There's a very important difference between Lojo's code and your code.  In Lojo's version, `A` is a generic class, while in yours it **implements** a parameterized type, but is not generic itself.

Answer (score 0):

The `SomethingThatExtendsA` class is a red herring here.  You get the same problem with

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("foo");
Iterator iterator = list.iterator(); // you should get a warning on this line...
String foo = iterator.next(); // ... and a compile error on this line
```

The issue is that **raw types** are a horrible ugly hack for backwards compatibility only which cause all the generics around them to stop working.  Specifically, `Iterator` is **not the same type** as `Iterator<String>`, `Iterator<Object>`, or even `Iterator<?>`.  Instead, `Iterator` means "the `Iterator` class I would have got if I had compiled with a pre-generics version of Java".  Since the pre-generics version of `Iterator` always returned `Object`, then that's what you get.  And you can't assign a value of type `Object` to a more specific type (like `String`, or your type `B`) without a cast.

The Java Language Specification says this:

> The use of raw types is allowed only as a concession to compatibility of legacy code. The use of raw types in code written after the introduction of genericity into the Java programming language is **strongly discouraged**. It is possible that **future versions of the Java programming language will disallow the use of raw types**.